# How can I print utf-8 and unicode tables from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, unicode

The ascii table can be displayed from the terminal using `man ascii`.

So, is there a package I can install to show the `utf-8` and `unicode` table from the terminal? For example, when I type `man utf-8`, a `utf-8` character table is displayed ; and when I type `man unicode`, a `unicode` character table is displayed.

Comment: Why do you need it? I have worked with people that are constantly looking up ascii codes. I have no idea why, as I do the same work without looking them up (or knowing them). Most programming languages let use use the character as a symbol for the code. All the programming languages that I have used recently(C, python, bash, html, css, javascript, …) allow we to include unicode into strings (direct / no codes). To aid typing of the non-ascii unicode characters, I have enabled and use the compose key.

Comment: In the pentesting world, they are needed a lot. Because you always need to put the unicode (or utf-8) presentation of a character when trying to test url parameters and other stuff.

Comment: You can use a url encoder. Also URLs don't contain utf-8: Then take the unicode code point and url encode it. (utf-8, utf-16, url encodeing, are all encodings. Unicode is what is encoded.)

Comment: You do realize that there are over one hundred thousand characters in Unicode, don't you? That would be one _big_ table. And UTF-8 is just an encoding for Unicode.

Comment: @AlexP I know that it is a big table, but the manual pages are compressed using gzip, so I doubt the manual page for such a table will even exceed 1Mb.

Comment: @Sidahmed: The problem is not the size of the manual page. The problem is finding a character in the huge table, not to mention that most likely there is no font having all the characters. You are much better off using an [online resource](http://unicode.org/resources/online-tools.html) such as Richard Ishida's [Uniview](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/).

Comment: Oh how many times have I seen an Ascii table in code implemented as an array ( 0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3, …………), this is what would be in the man page. The look up to glyphs (What they look like), is done by the rendering engine, of what ever is displaying the text.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one that I quickly hacked together. It needs a little work on the formatting, but basicly it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
for y in $(seq 0 524287)
  do
  for x in $(seq 0 7)
  do
    a=$(expr $y \* 8 + $x)
    echo -ne "$a \\u$a "
  done
  echo
done
```

Comment: not working on bash

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: it just prints out actual string "i.e. \\uXXXX" for some reason. in terminal - printf "\\uXXX" and echo -e "\uXXX" works.

Comment: What do you get if you type `type echo`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/5132 explains why this script does not work universally with the Bourne Again shell.

Comment: will not work with old bash, like MacOS's, @ jimmy-mg-lim. Upgrade bash to `echo -e` read unicode :) Thank you @ctrl-alt-delor